# Why does the Least Cost Intelligence path tool work on another computer but not mine?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, error-000354

For my final project in my GIS class, I am creating a least-cost path pipeline from a start point to an endpoint within a study area boundary (that being a park polygon). This tool takes a total cost surface (created from multiple rasters which have been reclassified), a start and end point  feature class (with the start and end points of the pipeline) and should create the pipeline.

When I run the arcpy.intelligence.LeastCostPath tool on my own computer through VScode the following error pops up.

```
ERROR: LeastCostPathLogic
  File "c:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\intel\mobility\LeastCostPath.py", line 265, in _costDistance
    out_cost_dist = sa.CostDistance(start_point,

Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Failed to execute (CostDistance).

Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Failed to execute (CostDistance).

ERROR: LeastCostPathLogic
  File "c:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\intel\mobility\LeastCostPath.py", line 596, in calculate
    out_cost_dist, out_backlink = self._costDistance(cost_surf,

cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
Start Time: April 16, 2023 10:31:20 PM
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Failed to execute (CostDistance).
Failed at April 16, 2023 10:31:20 PM (Elapsed Time: 0.07 seconds)
ERROR: LeastCostPath
  File "c:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcToolbox\Scripts\intel\mobility\MobilityToolClasses.py", line 180, in execute
    arcpy.SetParameter(3, mlcp_result[0])

'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000354: The name contains invalid characters
Failed to execute (CostDistance).
```

This error doesn't pop up when I use another computer which has PyScripter installed on it. Would anyone be able to explain what may be causing this error?

```
import arcpy
import os
import time
from arcpy.sa import *
from arcpy import env
import arcpy.mp as MAP



class FinalProjectClass():

    def __init__(self,outputGDBName,outputFolderPath,startPointFC,endPointFC,studyAreaPoly):
        #output gdb params
        self.outGDBname = outputGDBName
        self.outputFolder = outputFolderPath
        self.fulloutputGDB = os.path.join(self.outputFolder, self.outGDBname + ".gdb")

        #stores feature datasets on creation
        self.pointFD = ""
        self.polygonFD = ""
        self.lineFD = ""

        #set start point and end point data fc's.
        self.StartPoint = startPointFC
        self.endPoint = endPointFC

        #set study area polygon
        self.studyArea =studyAreaPoly
        self.studyAreaSet = ""


        #store coord system
        self.outputSR = "NAD 1983 UTM Zone 12N"
        self.outputDatum = "GCS_North_American_1983"

        #store river and road FCs
        self.riverFC = ""
        self.roadsFC = ""


        #store NTS50 FC
        self.NTS50 = ""

        #store the raw DEM and Land cover rasters
        self.DEM = ""
        self.LandcoverR = ""
        self.slopeDEM = ""
        self.Riverbuffer = ""
        self.roadBuffer = ""

        #store outputs of reclassification
        self.slopeClassified = ""
        self.landcoverClassified = ""
        self.riversClassified =""
        self.roadsClassified = ""

        #store remap values for each reclassification
        self.slopeRemap = [[0,3.9999,1],[4,10,2],[10,9999,3]]
        self.Landcoverremap = [[1,3],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,2],[7,3]]
        self.riverRemap =[[0,49.999,3],[50,250,2],[250,9999,1]]
        self.roadRemap =[[0,29.9999,1],[30,250,2],[250,9999,3]]


        self.totalCostSurface = ""

        self.pipelineVector = ""
    #checks if process was successfully completed
    def checkSuccessStatus(self):
        print("success status: ")
        print(arcpy.GetMessages())
        print("---------------------------------------------")


    #check if gdb from previous run exists, if it does, delete it, and create the gdb again.
    def setoutputGDB(self):
        if arcpy.Exists(self.fulloutputGDB):
            print("deleting previously created gdb")
            arcpy.Delete_management(self.fulloutputGDB)
        print("creating new output gdb")
        self.checkSuccessStatus()
        return arcpy.management.CreateFileGDB(self.outputFolder, self.outGDBname)

    #set feature datasets
    def setFDs(self):
        self.pointFD = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureDataset(self.fulloutputGDB,"Points",arcpy.SpatialReference(self.outputSR))
        self.polygonFD = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureDataset(self.fulloutputGDB,"Polygons",arcpy.SpatialReference(self.outputSR))
        self.lineFD = arcpy.management.CreateFeatureDataset(self.fulloutputGDB,"Lines",arcpy.SpatialReference(self.outputSR))


    #set study area
    def setStudyArea(self):
        self.studyAreaSet = self.projectFC(self.studyArea,"StudyArea",self.polygonFD,self.outputSR,self.outputDatum)

    #check feature class or shp to see if it is in the right coord system.
    def projectFC(self,FC,FC_outputName,outputWorkspace,outCoordSystem,outDatum):
        desc = arcpy.Describe(FC)
        spatialRef = desc.spatialReference
        print("check coordinate system of FC ",FC)
        #if feature coord system is unknown, shut program down and alert user.
        #If feature coordinate system is known check if it matches. If not, project it.
        if spatialRef.name  == "Unknown":
            print("error! Coordinate system of FC {},is unknown".format(FC), " please give it a coord system and try again")
            exit()
        elif spatialRef.name != "Unknown" and spatialRef.name != outDatum:
            print("changing datum to: {}".format(outDatum))
            return arcpy.management.Project(FC,str(outputWorkspace) + "\\{}".format(FC_outputName),arcpy.SpatialReference("NAD 1983 UTM Zone 12N"))
        elif(spatialRef.name  != outCoordSystem and spatialRef.name  == outDatum):
            print("The FC coordinate system has the correct datum, but is not projected yet. Projecting into the {} planar coordinate system".format(outCoordSystem))
            return arcpy.management.Project(FC,str(outputWorkspace) + "\\{}".format(FC_outputName),arcpy.SpatialReference("NAD 1983 UTM Zone 12N"))
        elif spatialRef.name  == outCoordSystem:
            print("doing import with no projecting needed")
        else:
            print("the datum is incorrect, please check the fc")
        self.checkSuccessStatus()

    #imports point features
    def importPointFeatures(self):
        startPointCopy = arcpy.conversion.ExportFeatures(self.StartPoint,str(self.fulloutputGDB) + "\\StartP_copy","""UFI = 'A21605053'""")
        endPointCopy = arcpy.conversion.ExportFeatures(self.endPoint,str(self.fulloutputGDB)+"\\End_P_copy","""UWID = '0074013407000'""")

        print("creating start and end points")
        self.StartPoint = self.projectFC(startPointCopy,"start",self.pointFD,self.outputSR,self.outputDatum)
        self.endPoint = self.projectFC(endPointCopy,"end",self.pointFD,self.outputSR,self.outputDatum)

        arcpy.Delete_management(startPointCopy)
        arcpy.Delete_management(endPointCopy)
        self.checkSuccessStatus()

    #imports line features and creates classified rasters from them.
    def importLineFeatures(self,workspace):
        walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass", type="Polyline")
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
            for filename in filenames:
                fullPath = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                print(filename)

                if ".gdb" not in filename and ".gdb" not in dirpath and ".gdb" not in dirnames:
                    #import roads and river feature classes. Then assign them to the roads and rivers global variables.
                    if "river" in filename:
                        print("projecting and clipping line feature: ", filename)
                        lineProjected = self.projectFC(fullPath,filename.replace(".shp","")+"projected",self.fulloutputGDB,self.outputSR,self.outputDatum)
                        self.riverFC = arcpy.analysis.Clip(lineProjected,self.studyAreaSet,str(self.lineFD) + "\\" + "rivers")

                        arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
                        arcpy.env.workspace = self.fulloutputGDB
                        print(self.studyAreaSet)
                        arcpy.env.extent = "StudyArea"
                        #create river buffers. Will need to add parameter to set extent to study area.
                        self.Riverbuffer =EucDistance(self.riverFC,cell_size="25")
                        self.riversClassified = Reclassify(self.Riverbuffer,"VALUE",RemapRange(self.riverRemap))
                        self.riversClassified.save(self.fulloutputGDB + "\\rivers_classified")

                        arcpy.Delete_management(lineProjected)

                    elif "roads" in filename:
                        print("projecting and clipping line feature: ", filename)
                        lineProjected = self.projectFC(fullPath,filename.replace(".shp","")+"projected",self.fulloutputGDB,self.outputSR,self.outputDatum)
                        self.roadsFC = arcpy.analysis.Clip(lineProjected,self.studyAreaSet,str(self.lineFD) + "\\" + "roads")

                        arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
                        print(self.studyAreaSet)
                        arcpy.env.workspace = self.fulloutputGDB
                        arcpy.env.extent = "StudyArea"
                        #create road buffers. Will need to add parameter to set extent to study area.
                        self.roadBuffer =EucDistance(self.roadsFC,cell_size="25")
                        self.roadsClassified = Reclassify(self.roadBuffer,"VALUE",RemapRange(self.roadRemap))
                        self.roadsClassified.save("roads_classified")

                        arcpy.Delete_management(lineProjected)
                    else:
                        continue

                elif ".gdb" in filename or ".gdb" in dirpath or ".gdb" in dirnames:
                    print("skipping the output gdb")
        self.checkSuccessStatus()

    #retrieves and organizes polygon features
    def importPolygonFeatures(self,workspace):
        PolyFeatureClasses = []
        #setup a walk variable with arcpy walk to loop through subfolders
        walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass", type="Polygon")
        #for each file in subfolder in main directory
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
            #look at subfolder path
            print("looking into the directory path: ", dirpath)
            #for each file in subfolder
            for filename in filenames:
                if ".gdb" not in filename and ".gdb" not in dirpath and ".gdb" not in dirnames:
                    print("looking into filename: ",filename)
                    #if park feature class or landcover feature class is accessed skip it.
                    if "park" in str(filename):
                        print("found the park feature class")

                    #if NTS50 polygon is found, clip it. Store the NTS50 value in a global variable
                    elif "NTS50" in filename:
                        polyProjected = self.projectFC(os.path.join(dirpath, filename),filename.replace(".shp","")+"_projected",self.fulloutputGDB,self.outputSR,self.outputDatum)
                        self.NTS50 = arcpy.analysis.Clip(polyProjected,self.studyAreaSet,str(self.polygonFD) + "\\" + filename.replace(".shp","")+"_clipped")
                        arcpy.Delete_management(polyProjected)
                    PolyFeatureClasses.append(filename)
                elif ".gdb" in filename and ".gdb" in dirpath and ".gdb" in dirnames:
                    continue
        self.checkSuccessStatus()


    #projects rasters
    def projectRaster_Custom(self,RasterInput,Raster_output,outputWorkspace,outCoordSystem,outDatum):

        desc = arcpy.Describe(RasterInput)
        spatialRef = desc.spatialReference
        print("check coordinate system of raster ",RasterInput)
        #if feature coord system is unknown, shut program down and alert user.
        #If feature coordinate system is known check if it matches. If not, project it.
        if spatialRef.name  == "Unknown":
            print("error! Coordinate system of FC {},is unknown".format(RasterInput), " please give it a coord system and try again")
            exit()

        elif spatialRef.name != "Unknown" and spatialRef.name != outDatum:
            print("changing datum to: {}".format(outDatum))
            return arcpy.management.ProjectRaster(RasterInput,str(outputWorkspace) + "\\{}".format(Raster_output),arcpy.SpatialReference(self.outputSR))

        elif(spatialRef.name  != outCoordSystem and spatialRef.name  == outDatum):
            print("The raster coordinate system has the correct datum, but is not projected yet. Projecting into the {} planar coordinate system".format(outCoordSystem))
            return arcpy.management.ProjectRaster(RasterInput,str(outputWorkspace) + "\\{}".format(Raster_output),arcpy.SpatialReference(self.outputSR))

        elif spatialRef.name  == outCoordSystem:
            print("doing import with no projecting needed")

        else:
            print("the datum is incorrect, please check the fc")
        self.checkSuccessStatus()

    #organizes and reclassifies all raster data
    def importRasterFeatures(self,workspace):
        RasterData = []
        walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace,datatype = "RasterDataset")

        DEM_rasters = []

        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
            print("looking into the directory path: ", dirpath)

            for filename in filenames:
                if ".gdb" not in filename and ".gdb" not in dirpath and ".gdb" not in dirnames:
                    print("looking at file: ",filename)
                    fullPath =os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                    print("found in folder location: ",dirpath)
                    desc = arcpy.Describe(fullPath)
                    RasterData.append(fullPath)
                    print("Data Type: " + desc.dataType)
                    if "dem" in filename:
                        print("storing DEM raster")
                        print("found the DEM",filename)
                        DEM_rasters.append(fullPath)

                    if "landcov" in filename:
                        print("found the landcover raster")
                        self.LandcoverR = self.projectRaster_Custom(fullPath,"Landcover_classes",self.fulloutputGDB,self.outputSR,self.outputDatum)

                        arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
                        arcpy.env.workspace = self.fulloutputGDB
                        arcpy.env.extent = "StudyArea"
                        self.landcoverClassified =  Reclassify(self.LandcoverR,"VALUE",RemapValue(self.Landcoverremap))
                        self.landcoverClassified.save("landcover_ranked")
                if ".gdb" in filename and ".gdb" in dirpath and ".gdb" in dirnames:
                    print("this is the output gdb, skipping")

        print("dem rasters found: ", DEM_rasters)

        DEM_unproj = arcpy.management.Mosaic(DEM_rasters,DEM_rasters[0])

        self.DEM = self.projectRaster_Custom(DEM_unproj,"DEM_merged",self.fulloutputGDB,self.outputSR,self.outputDatum)

        arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
        arcpy.env.workspace = self.fulloutputGDB
        arcpy.env.extent = "StudyArea"

        self.slopeDEM = Slope(self.DEM,"DEGREE")
        self.slopeDEM.save("slope_DEM")
        self.slopeClassified = Reclassify(self.slopeDEM,"VALUE",RemapRange(self.slopeRemap))
        self.slopeClassified.save("slope_ranked")

        print("list of rasters found: ", RasterData)


    #creates total cost surface.
    def createWeightedOverlay(self):

        env.workspace = self.fulloutputGDB

        remapScheme = RemapValue([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]])

        inRaster1 =  self.roadsClassified.name
        inRaster2 =  self.riversClassified.name
        inRaster3 =  self.landcoverClassified.name
        inRaster4 =  self.slopeClassified.name

        myWOTable = WOTable([[inRaster1, 15, "VALUE", remapScheme],
                     [inRaster2, 40, "VALUE", remapScheme],
                     [inRaster3, 30, "VALUE", remapScheme],
                     [inRaster4, 15, "VALUE", remapScheme]
                              ], [1, 3, 1])

        # create total cost surface.
        outWeightedOverlay = WeightedOverlay(myWOTable)

        outWeightedOverlay.save("fcostsurface")

        self.totalCostSurface = outWeightedOverlay

        print("total cost surface path is: ",self.totalCostSurface)
        print("start point vector", self.StartPoint)
        print("end point vector: ",self.endPoint)

        arcpy.ValidateTableName(self.pipelineVector)
        self.pipelineVector = arcpy.intelligence.LeastCostPath(self.totalCostSurface,self.StartPoint,self.endPoint,"pipelinevector")


        #'''     def createLeastCostPaths(self):
        #manual cost surface path: C:\GEOS456\FinalProject\CypressHills.gdb\fcostsurface
        # self.pipelineVector = arcpy.intelligence.LeastCostPath(self.totalCostSurface,self.StartPoint,self.endPoint,"pipelineVector") '''

    #def setRasterStats(self):
        #ZonalStatisticsAsTable

    #manual methods for faster debugging
    def populateFinalMap(self,aprxpath,finalaprxFolder):
        arcpy.env.workspace = self.fulloutputGDB
        #try without overwrite output first
        print("looking at aprx path of: ",aprxpath)
        aprx = MAP.ArcGISProject(aprxpath)
        aprx.saveACopy(str(aprxpath).replace(".aprx","")+"_BK.aprx")
        print("backup aprx path is: ",str(aprxpath).replace(".aprx","")+"_BK.aprx")
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
        maps = aprx.listMaps()

        for Map in maps:
            print(Map.name)
            print(Map.mapType)
            print(Map.mapUnits)
            print(Map.spatialReference.name)

        pipeline_map = aprx.listMaps("Pipeline Route")[0]

        fcList = ["pipelinevector","StudyArea","rivers","roads","end","start"]
        for fc in fcList:
            print("now attaching to pipeline map a file path of: {} to the pipeline map".format(fc))
            #create layer file from each feature class
            layer = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(fc)
            fcName = os.path.basename(str(fc))
            lyrFile = arcpy.management.SaveToLayerFile(layer,finalaprxFolder+"//"+fcName+".lyrx")
            #save every feature layer to layer file(.lyrx)


            #adds layers to map
            lyrFile = MAP.LayerFile(lyrFile)
            pipeline_map.addLayer(lyrFile)

            #summon the layout
            layout = aprx.listLayouts("GEOS456_FinalProject_Template")[0]

            #summon legend element
            legend = layout.listLayoutElements("LEGEND_ELEMENT", "Legend")[0]

            #for lyr in legend.listLegendItemLayers():
            #    lyr.name = fc.replace("_Layer","")
            #create list of layouts in arpx
        #layout = aprx.listLayouts()[0]

        aprx.saveACopy("{}\FinalAprx.aprx_BK".format(finalaprxFolder))
        layout.exportToPDF("{}\GEOS456_FP_Pan_Justin.pdf".format(finalaprxFolder))

    def printStatistics(self):
        arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
        arcpy.env.workspace = self.fulloutputGDB
        ElevAvg = ZonalStatisticsAsTable(self.studyArea,"NAME",self.DEM,"mean_elev_park")
        SlopeAvg  = ZonalStatisticsAsTable(self.studyArea,"NAME",self.slopeDEM,"mean_slope_park")


    def calculateLandcoverTypes(self):
        arcpy.management.AddField(self.LandcoverR,"Area_sqm","FLOAT")
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(self.LandcoverR,["VALUE","Area_sqm"]) as printLandcoverAreas:
            for row in printLandcoverAreas:
                print("area of landcover class {} is {} square meters".format(row[0],row[1]))

#manual methods for faster debugging
def populateFinalMapManual(outWorkspace,outputFCList,aprxpath,finalaprxFolder):
    arcpy.env.workspace = outWorkspace
    #try without overwrite output first
    print("looking at aprx path of: ",aprxpath)
    aprx = MAP.ArcGISProject(aprxpath)
    aprx.saveACopy(str(aprxpath).replace(".aprx","")+"_BK.aprx")
    print("backup aprx path is: ",str(aprxpath).replace(".aprx","")+"_BK.aprx")
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    maps = aprx.listMaps()

    for Map in maps:
        print(Map.name)
        print(Map.mapType)
        print(Map.mapUnits)
        print(Map.spatialReference.name)

    pipeline_map = aprx.listMaps("Pipeline Route")[0]

    fcList = outputFCList
    for fc in fcList:
        print("now attaching to pipeline map a file path of: {} to the pipeline map".format(fc))
        #create layer file from each feature class
        layer = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(fc)
        fcName = os.path.basename(str(fc))
        lyrFile = arcpy.management.SaveToLayerFile(layer,finalaprxFolder+"//"+fcName+".lyrx")
        #save every feature layer to layer file(.lyrx)


        #adds layers to map
        lyrFile = MAP.LayerFile(lyrFile)
        pipeline_map.addLayer(lyrFile)

        #summon the layout
        layout = aprx.listLayouts("GEOS456_FinalProject_Template")[0]

        #summon legend element
        legend = layout.listLayoutElements("LEGEND_ELEMENT", "Legend")[0]

        #for lyr in legend.listLegendItemLayers():
        #    lyr.name = fc.replace("_Layer","")
        #create list of layouts in arpx
    #layout = aprx.listLayouts()[0]

    aprx.saveACopy("{}\FinalAprx.aprx_BK".format(finalaprxFolder))
    layout.exportToPDF("{}\GEOS456_FP_Pan_Justin.pdf".format(finalaprxFolder))



def main():

    #inputs for C drive
##    outputFolderPath = r"C:\GEOS456\FinalProject"
##    outputGDBName = "CypressHills"
##
##    wellsFC = r"C:\GEOS456\FinalProject\Oil_Gas\wells.shp"
##    FacilitiesFC = r"C:\GEOS456\FinalProject\Oil_Gas\facilities.shp"
##    studyArea = r"C:\GEOS456\FinalProject\Base_72E09\rec_park.shp"
##    finalProjData = r"C:\GEOS456\FinalProject"
##
##    final_aprx = r"C:\GEOS456\FinalProject\Final_Project_arpx\Final_Project_aprx.aprx"


    #pipelineVectorManual = arcpy.intelligence.LeastCostPath('C:\\GEOS456\\FinalProject\\CypressHills.gdb\\fcostsurface','C:\\GEOS456\\FinalProject\\CypressHills.gdb\\Points\\start','C:\\GEOS456\\FinalProject\\CypressHills.gdb\\Points\\end','C:\\GEOS456\\FinalProject\\CypressHills.gdb\\pipelinevector')
    #exit(0)

    #final aprx path was changed for dad's computer


    # computer 2 file parameters
##    outputFolderPath = r"C:\GEOS456\Final_Project"
##    outputGDBName = "CypressHills"
##
##    wellsFC = r"C:\GEOS456\Final_Project\Oil_Gas\wells.shp"
##    FacilitiesFC = r"C:\GEOS456\Final_Project\Oil_Gas\facilities.shp"
##    studyArea = r"C:\GEOS456\Final_Project\Base_72E09\rec_park.shp"
##    finalProjData = r"C:\GEOS456\Final_Project"
##
##    final_aprx = r"C:\GEOS456\Final_Project\Final_Project__aprx\Final_Project__aprx.aprx"
##
##

    outputFolderPath = r"E:\FinalProject"
    outputGDBName = "CypressHills"

    wellsFC = r"E:\FinalProject\Oil_Gas\wells.shp"
    FacilitiesFC = r"E:\FinalProject\Oil_Gas\facilities.shp"
    studyArea = r"E:\FinalProject\Base_72E09\rec_park.shp"
    finalProjData = r"E:\FinalProject"

    final_aprx = r"E:\FinalProject\GEOS456_FinalProject_Template\GEOS456_FinalProject_Template.aprx"



    #for manual testing of mapping component
    #outputWorkspace = r"E:\FinalProject\CypressHills.gdb"
    #outputFCs = ["pipelinevector","StudyArea","rivers","roads","end","start"]

    #populateFinalMapManual(outputWorkspace,outputFCs,final_aprx,finalProjData)
    #end of manual testing for mapping component


    #exit()



    #start timer

    start = time.time()
    print("starting script")
    #create and instance of the final project class
    finalProject = FinalProjectClass(outputGDBName,outputFolderPath,FacilitiesFC,wellsFC,studyArea)


    #set the output gdb and delete previous gdb copy
    finalProject.setoutputGDB()

    #set the vector feature datasets
    finalProject.setFDs()

    #set the study area
    finalProject.setStudyArea()

    #import and clip the point features
    finalProject.importPointFeatures()

    #import and clip the polygon features
    finalProject.importPolygonFeatures(finalProjData)

    #import and clip the line features
    finalProject.importLineFeatures(finalProjData)

    #end timer and show total script time.
    finalProject.importRasterFeatures(finalProjData)

    #create cost surface and make pipeline

    finalProject.createWeightedOverlay()

    finalProject.populateFinalMap(final_aprx,finalProjData)

    #finalProject.populateFinalMap(final_aprx,finalProjData)
    end = time.time()
    print("the script ran for a total of: ",(end-start) * 10 **3,"ms or", ((end-start) * 10 **3)/60000," minutes")

    finalProject.populateFinalMap(final_aprx,finalProjData)
    # mapStep1(aprx,workspace)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Does the computer it is failing on conform to the [minimum specification](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/intelligence/intelligence-toolbox-license.htm) of this tool?

Comment: Also you simply provide a name for the output of the LeastCostPath tool which is "pipelinevector". If you read the help file you will see this tool does not honour any [environment settings](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/intelligence/least-cost-path.htm#ESRI_GPENVIRONMENT_F270B01425BC4C97838F0C9BF47BBDC4). The code samples show the tool taking a full path.

Comment: It's unclear whether this is a configuration issue or a coding error. Making a minimal reproducible example could help you determine the problem.

Comment: Check and fix the names of your tables and fields fro invalid characters or restricted names.  You are likely writing to a geodatabase with a different location if the error only happens on a different computer.  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.0/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00351-00375-000354.htm